# What can hold more weight, a wall stud or a ceiling joist?

Tags: ceiling, garage, storage, load

I'm planning on building some custom wood-framed storage near the ceiling of my garage. The things you can buy online seem to always be ceiling mounted (Example: [This product](https://www.fleximounts.com/classic-4-x-8-gr48?value=1-pack-gr48b&gclid=CjwKCAiA5L2tBhBTEiwAdSxJX1k3XLTtcwxb310JK-sfBA1TvmhiMF4myUUwCGqq0EciGeQulfNYeBoCAbkQAvD_BwE))

However, I also found a blog online which does theirs via a [wall mounted design](https://southhousedesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/The-Plans.jpeg), and a few YouTube DIY videos which do one or the other.

I want to do this once, and right - and I don't want my storage to come crashing down on me. I plan on storing things in storage bins like holiday decorations, baby toys/clothes, winter clothes, etc.

Above my garage is our master bathroom - I wanted to add this context since my understanding is that the construction of ceiling joists may differ depending on if they need to support a floor above versus just a roof. The joists are [wooden open-webbed trusses](https://www.carolinastructuralsystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Floors-900.jpg).

So my ultimate question is: What is safer/stronger for bearing the load? Wall mount? Ceiling Mount? and since I'm building my own, would I get significantly better benefits from mounting to both ceiling AND wall simultaneously?

Comment: All the things you mention storing are lightweight. No books, no anvils, no rock collections. Note that the wall stud will be holding the load up either way, since it holds up the joists (floor trusses in your case.)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, roof trusses are okay for light stuff, floor joists like you have up to medium weight(under your weight), and for heavy stuff you want walls studs and/or floor(no joists).

Comment: Remember that _current_ you will only store light weight stuff. _Future_ you (or the next owner of the house) might get a bit carried away and start storing heavy stuff. Also, a box of clothing (baby or adult) can get quite heavy, especially winter clothes.

Comment: If your ceiling or wall comes crashing down from storing things on the garage shelves, your house likely would have collapsed had you put those things upstairs. When shelves and cabinets fall unexpectedly, it's usually because they weren't attached properly, not because the structure they were attached to collapsed.

Comment: The question is vague and largely irrelevant. Your rack design and your mounting method are far more critical than what the house can hold. That's not a concern in this case.

Comment: You're thinking about garage storage poorly.  The wall shelf you linked seems awful.  Spinny rods with gaps between the and angle brackets that divie the shelf space uselessly.  What you want is BOTH wall and ceiling storage.  Things accessed more frequently go on the walls.  For wall storage just buy some traditional shelf brackets and put 10 inch planks on top.   For ceiling storage buy something like what you linked.  That one rightly shows how angle brackets are used to engage 6 or 9 joists in at least two places per joist.

Comment: The difficulty with truss joists is centering your screws on the relatively small bottom members.  Best thing is to remove some plaster to make sure you get it perfect.    If you can find the make and model of the trusses written on them you will then be able to find manufacturer's specific instructions of how and where to attach things and the load limits.

Comment: Aren't trusses, @jay613, usually made out of 2x lumber, the same as studs? Thus, the width available to hit with a screw is the same?

Comment: @FreeMan yes I think you're right actually.   I was recalling the difficulty I had when I once worked with these.  My own ceiling joists are actual (not dimensional) 2x and solid.  I put up these very ceiling shelves in MIL's garage, which is trusses with *double 5/8 drywall*.   And I couldn't use the 3 inch lag screws that came with the shelves, they went clear through the trusses.  But you're right, it wasn't the actual width of them that made it so hard.

Comment: @jay613, the strength of a fastener goes down significantly, though, if you miss a 1-1/2" edge's center by too much. I recall a Simpson technical guide with a +/-1/8" of center spec. There it is at the bottom of page 76: https://ssttoolbox.widen.net/view/pdf/oevlatgrb7/C-F-2023TECHSUP-p072-079.pdf. Whoops. It was +/-3/16". For lag screws I usually find the framing and use a tiny drill bit to poke every 1/4" until I find both edges. But if it's at the MIL's....

Comment: @popham it was MIL's *garage* so I didn't have to be too dainty.  I do that tiny drill thing a lot in my own home.  In her garage I ended up cutting open some 1-inch holes so I could see inside.  Double drywall with unevenly spaced joists, up to 19 inches but as little as 6 inches ... had me totally stumped.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming wood framed walls...

The walls wind up supporting the weight either way. Hanging from the joists may distribute the weight a bit more widely since they rest on the plate which is supported by the studs... but unless you're installing an engine hoist or a small elephant screwing into the studs is probably much more than strong enough. Wood has a *lot* of endwise compression strength, and screws taking sideways strain don't tend to rip out unless you have massively overloaded them.

Household cabinets screw to studs, directly or indirectly.

Comment: The eccentricity of load under wall mounting introduces bending stress into the wall studs, where the introduced compression stress is trivial in comparison. The ceiling load configuration uses the bending strength of the joists to transfer just a compression load into the wall. It results in the same compression stress as the wall mounting, but without the wall mount's bending stress. Compression and bending interact to reduce capacity. From [NDS](https://awc.org/publications/2018-nds/) Chapter 3, see 3.9-1 under 3.9.1 and pretend it's for compression instead of tension.

Comment: Hm. Granted. But in practice, for reasonable loads, is it a difference which actually makes a difference?

Comment: My intuition agreed with your distinction-without-a-difference, but after looking at it, I wouldn't want a 4 ft deep shelf attached to a load bearing wall (without legs down to the floor). For kids crawling all over the thing, I expect that the 1.6 load duration factor bails me out with extra strength, but I would want a flimsy surface or something to deter heavy long term loads. Thinking way ahead, I would feel guilty leaving a ticking time bomb for somebody "fixing" my deterrent. I would put a beam along the wall to share load across studs or etch a capacity tag that mentions the wall.

Comment: If you have a 4' deep shelf, I expect you are supporting it at the front edge as well; otherwise NOTHING is going to hold. Whether that support is from above or below is up to you. I have a set of  open shelves that are about 16" deep and supporting upward of 600 pounds of lumber, but they're hanging from a square-steel-tube backplane which is lag-bolted to the studs in three places to distribute forces -- and as complete overkill , the top two bolts are actually tapcons going through into the cement behind this wall, which are as much about making other people comfortable as convincing myself

Comment: Yeah, I based it off of 45 degree kickers from underneath and 2.5 ft distance from shelf to 7 ft ceiling, with the 45 degrees implying a 4 ft distance from shelf down to the kicker's wall anchorage. There's typically lots of reserve strength in wall construction because of the 30 psf or 40 psf live load spec for floors (which seems excessive). Given something like a single story house with 2x4 studs on 24" centers, though, when a big snow load appears on the roof I might start to sweat a little. For 2 or 3 stories of 30 psf or 40 psf live loading that never shows up, I can't imagine regrets.

Comment: See also all the past questions from people who wanted to build floating desks.

Comment: Why would anybody want a desk in their pool? :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't like hanging things from trusses, especially when you can't see the panel points where the bottom chord is stiffened by web members. The top chords are probably sized to support 10 psf dead load plus 30 psf live load (30 psf because of the sleeping room above) and the bottom chords probably use the same material, so by assuming a 2 ft spacing between panel points and assuming a 16" joist spacing, I anticipate a bending strength of (10psf + 30psf)(16")(1ft/12")(2ft)<sup>2</sup>/8. This corresponds to a mid-panel point concentrated load of P(2ft)/4, where solving for P yields a maximum concentrated load of 53#. If you attach to the bottom chord without looking at the panel points and hit exactly halfway between two panel points, then, there's not much strength available. And technically that bottom chord is doing other stuff, where its tension will rob some from that 53# anticipated strength. (53# per support may sound like a lot, but don't forget about mischievous child loads.)

Further, I don't like attaching exactly at panel points out of fear of damaging the connection plates. I would argue, then, that there's a "sweet spot" 3 inches or so to either side of the panel points for hanging loads. General advice without quality control beyond an owner's diligence? Go with wall mounting.

For wall mounting, try to avoid bracing shallower than, say, 45°, as the loading in and out of the wall increases as the brace approaches flat. For a uniformly distributed 100# load over a 4 ft deep shelf and one brace to the wall, the in and out load at the wall will be 50# out at the high support point and 50# in at the low support point (assuming 45° bracing), where this can be a non-trivial load. For stud grade SPF 2x4s (you could have 2x6s for all I know), the bending strength is (675psi)(1/6)(1.5")(3.5")<sup>2</sup> = 2100 #-in, versus the 50# in and out loads with a bending demand of something like 850 #-in. The hypothetical stud grade SPF 2x4 loaded to 40% of capacity. In a load bearing wall that 40% goes up because of the interaction of axial compression with bending strength.

The trick if you have lots of weight is to have lots of braces to divide the weight up across many wall studs. Some kind of stiff beam along the wall can improve aesthetics by reducing brace count while still loading many wall studs.